# img HTML tag not honoring the HTTP Refresh header (but loading image URL in the browser does)

Tags: html, django, image, nginx, http-headers

I'm serving a placeholder image with an HTTP Refresh header, like this:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:image/gif
Date:Thu, 01 Aug 2013 14:16:25 GMT
Refresh:10; url=/media/thumbs/document/18.png
Server:nginx/1.4.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

If I load the image placeholder URL in the full window, the content is refreshed after 10 seconds, but if I put the same URL in the image tag `src` property, the image is never refreshed (tested in Chrome and FF).

Why am I doing this? I have an application where the thumbnail of a document takes a few seconds to be generated by the server (it is a complex SVG rendering). When the user goes to the document list right after creating a new document, the thumbnail may be not there yet. I was trying to use a placeholder image with a refresh header to load the real thumbnail after a few seconds.

I can't recall how, but back in the good old days of the Netscape browser, something like the refresh header was how we hacked animation sometimes (it was even before Flash - am I prehistoric or what?). We called it "server push" (I guess the the buzzword was recycled with the [Comet model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)).

I'm using Angular.js at the client side (server side is Django+uWSGI+Nginx), so it should be easy enough to hack something using javascript, yet I'm curious: **is there any trick (without javascript) to make the image tag load another source after a few seconds?**

(I will tag this Django and Nginx as well because may be someone knows a server-side solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

When you open an image directly in the browser, it's wrapped up as an HTML document.

Go to google's latest doodle jpg then open up your HTML console (http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/erwin_schrdingers_126th_birthday-2002007-hp.jpg).

In Chrome you'll get:

```
<html><body style="margin: 0px;">
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/erwin_schrdingers_126th_birthday-2002007-hp.jpg">
</body></html>
```

This "wrapping" isn't done for IMG tag src's that are inside of a document.

**Solution**

If you are intent on using just HTTP headers you're stuck with the multipart/x-mixed-replace described by @JamesHolderness, **but note** leaving HTTP connections hanging open like this can hurt your server performance and potentially open you up to a DDoS attack.

I was going to suggest using CSS animation / transition to lazy load an image. Unfortunately only Chrome support background-image (CSS property) animation. Another option would of been display: none since the image doesn't load until the element is displayed, but no browser supports animating or transitioning on the display (CSS property).

Here's the Chrome only, CSS only solution http://jsfiddle.net/r2Tag/

HTML

```
<div id="thumbnail"></div>
```

CSS

```
#thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    width: 475px;
    height: 184px;
    background-image:url('http://lh3.ggpht.com/Z9Bl8P_zqvnB_FPBw5PqZlHelALdwWoBV5EZSEVI85kS698xDzghSmLzREcaS1Uh31L5PIRdAiuMUcBSNlBGCsc-9YshQaxnMA4uzU2c-Q');
    animation: loadthumbnail 0s linear 10s;
    -webkit-animation: loadthumbnail 0s linear 10s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes loadthumbnail { to {
    width: 491px;
    height: 190px;
    background-image:url('https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/erwin_schrdingers_126th_birthday-2002007-hp.jpg');
} }
@-webkit-keyframes loadthumbnail { to {
    width: 491px;
    height: 190px;
    background-image:url('https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/erwin_schrdingers_126th_birthday-2002007-hp.jpg');
} }
```

**EDIT** If you use a data URI SVG as the background-image you animate to you can circumvent Chrome's parser pre-loading the image.

Example SVG

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="491px" height="190px" viewbox="0 0 491 190" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image externalResourcesRequired="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/erwin_schrdingers_126th_birthday-2002007-hp.jpg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/></svg>

background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
```

Comment: I wish I could split the bounty; my dumb solomonic solution was to accept your answer and award the bounty to James (I probably will just get both of you upset, but well, life is unfair).

Comment: @PauloScardine - Well both answers fall short of a safe & universal solution. When you start fiddling with HTTP headers and hanging connections or browser specific CSS, neither is optimal. The only safe and universal solutions are JavaScript or an IFRAME with a META refresh.

Comment: I don't have a problem with not having my answer accepted, but I am surprised the CSS solution worked for you (on any browser). It was one of the first things I tried, but for me it always seemed to load both images up front, even though the second image is only displayed later. I thought the idea was to load the second image after a delay (once you knew it would be ready), not just display it after a delay.

Comment: If that is not a problem, though, you can get the CSS animation solution to work on more browsers just by having two *img* tags that are positioned on top of each other and animating the *opacity* of the second one from 0 to 1 (or any number of other ways of hiding and showing that can be animated - moving it offscreen, setting the width/height to 0, setting the z-index to a negative value).

Comment: @JamesHolderness - You're right James, Chrome's parser pulls the image out of the @ keyframes and loads it before the animation starts. Maybe I can get even trickier using SVG...

Comment: @LouisRicci Since when is JavaScript support universal? True, experience with it turned off will almost always be lousy, but it does happen in paranoid corporates.

Comment: @PhilLello - It's a Web App (from the question: *I'm using Angular.js at the client side*). Since OP is already using a JavaScript framework on the client side I'd imagine JavaScript is required to use the Web App. I tink JavaScript support became universal when Web Apps became ubiquitous. I don't think JavaScript should be needed to view a Web Site, but really getting into pedantic disussions about the definitin of Web App vs Web Site is a waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to support IE, and your svg generation doesn't take so long that it would cause a connection to timeout, you can achieve a similar effect using a Content-Type of `multipart/x-mixed-replace`. Something like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=myboundary
```

For your actual content, you start by writing out the placeholder images like this:

```
--myboundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: <size of the image in bytes>

<binary image data + CR/LF>
```

Then immediately flush the output, but keep the connection alive (i.e. this will use a chunked Transfer-Encoding).

Now you can start generating your svg, and when it is finished, write it out like this:

```
--myboundary
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Content-Length: <size of the image in bytes>

<svg image data + CR/LF>
--myboundary--
```

This is basically how [streaming M-JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#M-JPEG_over_HTTP) works, only in this case the frames aren't all jpeg images.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to put your image into iframe, and return a page for that iframe with the Refresh header.

But, seriously, use JS.

Comment: I've made a "refresh" directive in angular that does the job, but I'm still curious if any combination of headers can do the trick.